# Loopcut in a script

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I'm a beginner in Blender and I want to do a loopcut in a script, and I saw that it was possible only in 3D view.

Is that why this command doesn't work?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1,
                                            "smoothness":0,
                                            "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE',
                                            "edge_index":81,
                                            "mesh_select_mode_init":(False, True, False)},
                           TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-0.25, 
                                            "single_side":False, 
                                            "use_even":False,
                                            "flipped":False, 
                                            "use_clamp":True, 
                                            "mirror":False, 
                                            "snap":False, 
                                            "snap_target":'CLOSEST', 
                                            "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), 
                                            "snap_align":False, 
                                            "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), 
                                            "correct_uv":True, 
                                            "release_confirm":False, 
                                            "use_accurate":False})
```

Is there someone who has a solution to by-pass this problem?

PS: Sorry for my bad english, I'm french

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass a custom context override as a positional argument:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override, MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":1, ...}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":-0.25, ...})
```

The override can be defined as follows:

```
window        = bpy.context.window
screen        = window.screen
view_3d_areas = [area for area in screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
regions       = [region for region in view_3d_areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
scene         = bpy.context.scene

override = {'window':window,
            'screen':screen,
            'area'  :view_3d_areas[0],
            'region':regions[0],
            'scene' :scene,
            'edit_object':scene.objects.active
            }
```

Also note that the active object needs to be of type `MESH` and in edit-mode. You can check for this with the following code:

```
active_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
if active_obj.type != "MESH":
    # alert user that active object must be of type 'MESH'
if active_obj.mode != "EDIT":
    # alert user that active object is not in edit mode
```